# How to change source in html5 video with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I have an html5 video streaming and I need to change it source* after some click action. So what i'm doing works, but only in html, i can see source change but it no changing on my display, can you help me? What is wrong? *The source is appending frome xml file.

HTML

```
<video autoplay loop width="960" height="540" id="video">
    <source src="video/movie_01.mp4" id="tv_main_channel">
</video>
```

JS

```
btn.on('click', function(){
    var tv_main_channel = $('#tv_main_channel'),
        d_program_source_mp4 = $(program_self).find("program_source_mp4").text();

    tv_main_channel.attr('src', d_program_source_mp4);
}
```

also i try it with `append` but it still not work

```
var video_block = $('#video');

video_block.empty();
video_block.append(
    '<source src="'+ d_program_source_mp4 +'">'
);
```

Thx for help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's simple, just do this:

```
btn.on("click", function(){
  var src = "new_video_src.mp4";
  $("#video").find("#tv_main_channel").attr("src", src)
})
```

Answer (score 28):

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qGbzb/2/

To dynamically load videos you need to run

```
var video_block = $('#video');
video_block.load();
```

Then you should also see a change in the display too, and not only in the html.

Comment: Thanks man, I was stuck there for hours, but calling the `.load()` solved it!

Comment: I had to do `$('#video')[0].load();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this in click event

```
  var src = "new_video_src.mp4";
  $("#tv_main_channel").src=src;
```

This is the actual method for video tag elements