# Append Json to <video> via AJAX (ASP.NET)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, ajax

I have AJAX call that works and return me JSON

Here is AJAX call

```
<script>
$('#display').click(function () {
    var vacancyId = $("#vacancy").val();
    var model = {
        vacancyId: vacancyId
};

    $.ajax({
url: '@Url.Action("Links", "Questions")',
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
data: JSON.stringify(model),
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
processData: false,
success: function (data) {
    var question2 = data[0];
    $(".videolist").append('<video>' + question2.Linkes + '</video>');
}
});
```

});

I need to append `<video>` block where `src` will be `question2.Linkes`

How I can do this?

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: I don't understood how put `question2.Linkes` to src of video block@Kumar_Vikas

Comment: You need to change the src of the video with jquery? If yes : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14799172/how-to-change-source-in-html5-video-with-jquery

Comment: @Eugene what does your `question2.Linkes` contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you video file is mp4.

You have to use below.

```
var videoHTML = '<video>';
videoHTML += '<source src="'+question2.Linkes+'" type="video/mp4">';
videoHTML += '</video>';
$('.videolist').append(videoHTML)
```

Comment: It works well, but one thing , it gets src like `http://localhost:51542/Interwier/uploads/130227898.webm`

and I need `http://localhost:51542/uploads/130227898.webm`

I made code like this now
` videoHTML += '<source src="' + "uploads/"+question2.Linkes + ".webm"+'" type="video/webm">';`

Comment: Have one question, if I has many links in json array, how I can display all?